# Riemann integrability - proof of an integrable function

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow [a,b]$ be Riemann integrable with $a<c<b$. Show that $\int_a^cf$ and $\int_c^bf$ both exist. Use the definition of Riemann's criterion for integrability.

I don't really understand the question - surely if a function is Riemann integrable then its integral exists?

Comment: Not sure if this is what the question is asking, but it might be asking you to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, c]$ and $[c, b]$ separately

Comment: I hadn't thought of it like that but I believe that's what the question is asking - how would one prove this?

Comment: Do you know the Riemann criterion for integrability?  For every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a partition $P$ such that the difference of upper and lower sums satisfies $U(P,f) - L(P,f) < \epsilon$ if and only if $f$ is Riemann integrable.  That provides an easy way to prove this.

Comment: I do know this criterion, however it's difficult for me to know how to approach this as it appears trivial (I know this to be a false sense of hope mostly though!)

Answer (score 3):

Let us focus on $[a, c]$.

Given any $\epsilon > 0,$ you wish to show that there exists a partition $\mathcal{P}$ of $[a, c]$ such that $$U(\mathcal{P}, f) - L(\mathcal{P}, f) < \epsilon.$$

Now, since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, you know that that there exists a partition $\mathcal{Q}$ of $[a, b]$ such that $$U(\mathcal{Q}, f) - L(\mathcal{Q}, f) < \epsilon.$$

From this, we may first get a partition $\mathcal{Q}' = \mathcal{Q} \cup \{c\}$ of $[a, b]$. Note that this is a refinement and hence,
$$U(\mathcal{Q}', f) - L(\mathcal{Q}', f) < \epsilon.$$

From the above, there is an obvious partition $\dot{\mathcal{Q}}$ of $[a, c]$ that you can get. Do you see what it is? Moreover, the above difference $(U - L)(\mathcal{Q}', f)$ is a certain sum of *non-negative* real numbers. When considering the corresponding difference for $\dot{\mathcal{Q}}$, we are just ignoring some of those terms. Thus, we get $$U(\dot{\mathcal{Q}}, f) - L(\dot{\mathcal{Q}}, f) < \epsilon,$$
as desired.